# Go beyond what you normally can do, with me!

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> From hunting to movie watching, I'm sought out,
> Even on birthdays or Christmas day, there's no doubt.
>
> Envied by many, who live a boring life,
> Let's be careful though, I can bring you much strife.
>
> In cases of life and death, I'm there the most,
> Never dull, nor fearful, I strengthen my host.
>
> Gone as fast as I come, but I'll come again,
> So don't be a junkie, 'cause you'll see me then.

What am I?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are:

> **THRILL**

From hunting to movie watching, I'm sought out,

> The thrill of a hunt, movies that are thrillers

Even on birthdays or Christmas day, there's no doubt.

> The thrill of gifts on these occasions

Envied by many, who live a boring life,

> They'd love to have some thrill to spice up their life

Let's be careful though, I can bring you much strife.

> Thrill-seeking behaviour can be risky/dangerous to life and limb

In cases of life and death, I'm there the most,

> Near-death experiences give the biggest thrill

Never dull, nor fearful, I strengthen my host.

> Thrills are the opposite of dull, thrill-seekers are not fearful/timid
>  Thrills release adrenalin, which gives the host a boost of energy (the flight/fright/fight syndrome)

Gone as fast as I come, but I'll come again,

> The thrills come as a rush, and dissipate after some time

So don't be a junkie, 'cause you'll see me then.

> Don't become a thrill-seeking adrenaline junkie

Comment: That is correct, nice job.

Comment: You know what, @Joe-You-Know , I think I'm answering a bunch of your riddles. Next time you put one up, I'll hold off on answering it, it's doesn't seem fair to me to be hogging your riddles.

Comment: Okay, I'm just surprised these get solved so quickly.

Comment: I'm sure you've seen other puzzles as well, but if anything, your puzzles are too well constructed :-). They aim for a single word, and have several clues which help eliminate alternative answers (which is a good thing), but which ends up leading one straight to the right answer or two. As a next step, maybe you could get a collection of related words, and give one clue for each, and ask people to explain all of them plus the common theme.  [contd...]

Comment: [...contd] e.g. In this case... seeing as you're working with feelings or emotions, maybe one clue for each emotion, which makes it harder to guess each one? That way, we'd have to work harder to figure each one out, but they will start reinforcing each other as the common thread becomes apparent.

Comment: That's a great idea, thanks, I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: You know something amusing I just noticed? My suggestion to you ties in to the title of your riddle :-)

Comment: In addition to Phylyp's notes, I'd suggest coming up with a way to reinforce the answer other than rot13[Npebfgvp].

Answer (score 4):

Are you

> Excitement?

From hunting to movie watching, I'm sought out,
Even on birthdays or Christmas day, there's no doubt.

> You can get a blood rush during a scary movie or get excited on Christmas.

Envied by many, who live a boring life,
Let's be careful though, I can bring you much strife.

> Boring lives are missing excitement, but you do not want to much craziness.

In cases of life and death, I'm there the most,
Never dull, nor fearful, I strengthen my host.

> Fight or flight.

Gone as fast as I come, but I'll come again,
So don't be a junkie, 'cause you'll see me then.

> Excitement can come fast?

Also

> the first letter of each line spell FEELINGS.

Comment: I like this answer, but it isn't what I'm looking for. It's really close to this though.