# Eyes on the Prize

Tags: riddle, word

> You rush to the edge of a cliff-
>   I in turn greet you.
>   You slam open the door of a plane-
>   I know you want me. You'll jump.
>   You yield to me; I'll be the end of you.
>
> I deliver the prize,
>   You remember my worth.
>   I uncloak your wild side,
>   You get up to do it again.

If you are you, then I am who?
Inspired by [this riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/69191/necessary-to-live-painful-to-bear).

Comment: You may like this riddle too, https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/67511/go-beyond-what-you-normally-can-do-with-me, as it is similar to this one.

Comment: I can only imagine how many puzzles on here use this answer... I like yours better, and I bet it wasn't written in two minutes like mine :^)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you

> Thrill or adrenaline?

You rush to the edge of a cliff-
I in turn greet you.
You slam open the door of a plane-
I know you want me. You'll jump.
You yield to me; I'll be the end of you.

> All of these things sound like someone who is an adrenaline junkie. It can lead to death

I deliver the prize,

> Which is adrenaline

You remember my worth.

> It helps you fight or run away.

I uncloak your wild side,

> Like bungee jumping, or sky gliding.

You get up to do it again.

> Because it releases dopamine into your brain, people keep doing more and more dangerous stuff to get the Thrill.

Edit:
There is an acrostic in the second word of each line that spells:

> risky drug

Comment: Since the prize has been awarded- rot13(Vg'f vafcverq ol gur fnzr npebfgvp gnpgvp lbh hfrq!)

Comment: Really? I'll have to look for it.

Answer (score 2):

## beat by Joe-You-Know

Are you a

> Adrenalin

You rush to the edge of a cliff-

> Maybe a plane door.

I in turn greet you.

> Fast heart rate and anticipation

You slam open the door of a plane-

> I want to skydive.

I know you want me. You'll jump.

> A big rush.

You yield to me; I'll be the end of you.

> Maybe to intense?

I deliver the prize,

> rush

You remember my worth.

> Fun

I uncloak your wild side,

> Adrenaline rush.

You get up to do it again.

> Addictive

Comment: Hopefully a rot13(cnenpuhgr) is *not* the end of you; I think their job is the exact opposite!

Comment: I thought the exact same thing!

Comment: @iiiidk, I though that clue meant something else... It should save you

Comment: Ohh@iiiidk rot13(nqeranyvar)

Comment: Beat you to it by seconds :D. I was already writing the answer when you first posted.

Comment: You get a definite +1 :D

Comment: I was writing my answer when he posted his first answer!

Comment: Accept Joe-you-know answer, 'cause I am maxed out.